# How to identify different loop types in LLVM IR, such as while, for and do-while?

Tags: loops, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to identify while loops in LLVM IR, I have using LoopInfoWrapperPass to get the loopInfo.

> LoopInfo &LoopInfo = getAnalysis(*F).getLoopInfo();

I do not find related API to distinguish among different loop types.

Comment: LoopInfo &LoopInfo = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>(*F).getLoopInfo();

Comment: There's no way to distinguish a while-loop from an equivalent for-loop at the LLVM level since they will generate the exact same LLVM code.

Comment: @sepp2k Thank you very much

Comment: @LingyunSITU: But from the basic block name you can identify what is which loop right

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it? `LoopInfo &LoopInfo = getAnalysis(*F).getLoopInfo();` doesn't provide API to distinguish different types of loops. Also, the LLVM IR code doesn't contain indicators to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

For LLVM IR, if you take a look at the [Loop](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Loop.html) API there are relevant calls like [getStartLoc](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Loop.html#a615131659002c10601eef598d42d025e). So you could do something like this (e.g. inside the `runOn` method of a `llvm::Function` pass):

```
llvm::SmallVector<llvm::Loop *> workList;
auto &LI = getAnalysis<llvm::LoopInfoWrapperPass>(CurFunc).getLoopInfo();

std::for_each(LI.begin(), LI.end(), [&workList](llvm::Loop *e) { workList.push_back(e); });

for(auto *e : workList) {
      auto line = e->getStartLoc().getLine();
      auto *scope = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::DIScope>(e->getStartLoc().getScope());
      auto filename = scope->getFilename();

      // do stuff here
    }
```

Now here from the source code line you can identify what kind of loop it is.